# Search JS using Div's and Structured Lists

Tags: javascript, search

I'm trying to create a search function but not able to make it work properly. No results are displayed. I see that the input is being processed "onkeyup" but instead of showing the results, it just shows me an empty screen. I believe it's because the depth level of Div's but I don't know for sure.

[image]

I've set the Input field class to match the JS and I see something is running. I just don't know why it's not showing the result. For simple UL LI structure seems to work.

I'm new and study JS and like to learn on the job so I'm researching for a solution still.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form class="page-search-form" role="search">
  <div class="input-search input-search-dark">
    <i class="input-search-icon md-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="myInput" name="search" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search Users">

    <button type="button" class="input-search-close icon md-close" aria-label="Close"></button>
  </div>
</form>
<ul class="list-group" id="myUL">



  <li class="list-group-item">
    <div class="media">
      <div class="pr-0 pr-sm-20 align-self-center">
        <div class="avatar avatar-online">
          <img src="../../../global/portraits/1.jpg" alt="...">
          <i class="avatar avatar-busy"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="media-body align-self-center">
        <h5 class="mt-0 mb-5 name">
          Herman Beck
          <small>Last Access: 1 hour ago</small>
        </h5>
        <p>
          <i class="icon icon-color md-pin" aria-hidden="true"></i> Street 4425 Golf Course Rd
        </p>
        <div>
          <a class="text-action" href="javascript:void(0)">
            <i class="icon icon-color md-email" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </a>
          <a class="text-action" href="javascript:void(0)">
            <i class="icon icon-color md-smartphone" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </a>
          <a class="text-action" href="javascript:void(0)">
            <i class="icon icon-color bd-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </a>
          <a class="text-action" href="javascript:void(0)">
            <i class="icon icon-color bd-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </a>
          <a class="text-action" href="javascript:void(0)">
            <i class="icon icon-color bd-dribbble" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="pl-0 pl-sm-20 mt-15 mt-sm-0 align-self-center">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Follow</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just realized my mistake by replacing:
a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
to
a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("h5")[0];

Answer (score 0):

Something like this much simplified script

You As do not have content. The H5 or media-body does

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  const lis = document.querySelectorAll("#myUL li");

  document.getElementById("myInput").addEventListener("input", function() {
    const filter = this.value.toUpperCase().trim();
    lis.forEach(li => {
      if (filter === "") li.classList.remove("hide");
      else {
        const textContainer = li.querySelector(".media-body");
        const txtValue = textContainer.textContent.toUpperCase();
        li.classList.toggle("hide", !txtValue.includes(filter))
      }
    })
  })
})
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form class="page-search-form" role="search">
  <div class="input-search input-search-dark">
    <i class="input-search-icon md-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="myInput" name="search" placeholder="Search Users">

    <button type="button" class="input-search-close icon md-close" aria-label="Close"></button>
  </div>
</form>
<ul class="list-group" id="myUL">



  <li class="list-group-item">
    <div class="media">
      <div class="pr-0 pr-sm-20 align-self-center">
        <div class="avatar avatar-online">
          <img src="../../../global/portraits/1.jpg" alt="...">
          <i class="avatar avatar-busy"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="media-body align-self-center">
        <h5 class="mt-0 mb-5 name">
          Herman Beck
          <small>Last Access: 1 hour ago</small>
        </h5>
        <p>
          <i class="icon icon-color md-pin" aria-hidden="true"></i> Street 4425 Golf Course Rd
        </p>
        <div>
          <a class="text-action" href="javascript:void(0)">
            <i class="icon icon-color md-email" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </a>
          <a class="text-action" href="javascript:void(0)">
            <i class="icon icon-color md-smartphone" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </a>
          <a class="text-action" href="javascript:void(0)">
            <i class="icon icon-color bd-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </a>
          <a class="text-action" href="javascript:void(0)">
            <i class="icon icon-color bd-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </a>
          <a class="text-action" href="javascript:void(0)">
            <i class="icon icon-color bd-dribbble" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="pl-0 pl-sm-20 mt-15 mt-sm-0 align-self-center">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Follow</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
```